# C++ delete operation related query

Tags: c++, class, templates, delete-operator

I want to understand something about dynamic memory: new and delete for a class template as below.

I have class template defined by some library(in house developed) which defines
the class template as below.

```
template <class DAT, class IDX, int ENTRYMX=0x20, int SUBMX=34, int bsz=8> 
class HashTable : public public HashTableIn
{
HashTable () 
: HashTableIn(ENTRYMX),
  ...


...
...
}
```

In my code I use  an object of that template class as:

```
mpRt = new HashTable<data_st,index_st>;
```

and I delete this mpRt explicitly as( I know smart pointers... but currently they arent used in this legacy code so lets leave them out)

```
delete mpRt;
```

My question:
  I am trying to understand whether Do i have to do

```
delete [] mpRt

because the class template has a default argument of ENTRYMX = 0x20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to understand whether Do i have to do `delete [] mpRt`

No, you allocate `mpRt` by `operator new` then you call `delete mpRt;` You have to call `new/delete` and `new [] /delete[]` in pair.

If you use `ENTRYMX` inside `HashTable` to dynamically allocate memory with `new[]`, you need to call `delete[]` inside `HashTable` to deallocate it. Also don't forget to follow [Rule of Three.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: In C++ 11 rule of Three now is the Rule of five(move semantics). Very strange question for user with such rating, maybe some additional info is omitted and goldenmean should edit his question to make it more clear/ although +1 for evident answer )

Comment: @spin_eight It's still rule of three.  Supporting move semantics is an optimization, only done when the profiler says you must.  (On the other hand, it's more or less a non-rule today: application level classes should generally be designed so that the defaults do the right thing.)

Comment: @ James Kanze supporting move semantics add`s move constructor and move assignement operator therefore the Rule of 3 evolves to the Rule of 5 )

Answer (score 2):

From the standard :

> **5.3.4 New [expr.new]**
>
> 8/ If the allocated type is a non-array type, the allocation function’s name is `operator new` and the deallocation function’s name is `operator delete`. If the allocated type is an array type, the allocation function’s name is `operator new[]` and the deallocation function’s name is `operator delete[]`.

**`new` comes always with `delete`.**

**`new []` comes always with `delete []`.**

In your case, `mpRt` is allocated with the `operator new`, you must deallocate it with `delete`.

Comment: It's more complex than that.  First, even if he did allocate an array, `mpRt` would have exactly thee same type.  Secondly, it's important to realize that `new[]` has nothing to do with the tokens used in the `new` expression; it's quite possible to have an array `new` without any `[]`, or a plain `new` with `[]` in the new expression.  You have to analyze the type itself, to see if it is actually an array.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you ? `mpRt` isn't an array allocated with `new[]`.

It may contain an array (as hints the argument name `ENTRYMX`), but `mpRt` isn't of an array type in itself. The management of the memory related to this array is internal to the class, and not the responsibility of the code that creates object of this class.

Rule of thumb : match `new`s with `delete`s and `new type[]`s with `delete []`s.

Answer (score 1):

No, always use new/delete and new[]/delete[] in pair. So don't use delete[] if you haven't explicitly used new[]